# HTML/PHP Form Doesn't Submit

Tags: php, html

I have created a form for something i call a site survey. Before i had the form one one page. But decided to spread it across three html/css tabs. At first it did let me submit to a MySQL db. But I didn't make a backup of a working example with the tabs as it wasn't fully what I wanted yet.

Now it glitches and wont create a new record in the db

### Problem

I fill in the first part of the form which works Okay. I click next to send me to the next tab. and go to fill in the rest of the form. I am instantly seeing one of the "please fill out this field" because it is "required" in the code. Once filled, i press the next button again. Which this   then takes me to the next tab but then instantly to the first tab and refreshes everything

The next and previous buttons work and dont glitch when there are no answers entered into the fields

I have no idea how to solve the problem. Which is why I'm seeing if anyone can help.

### edit

I changed the button to an A tag like the "previous" a tag does. This stops the glitches. However the form does not submit...
Function for the Next/Previous button to work -

```js
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.next-button').click(function(){
            $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
            //trigger the click on the tab same like we click on the tab
        });

        $('.previous-button').click(function(){
            $('.nav-tabs > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
            //trigger the click on the tab same like we click on the tab
        })
    </script>
```

HTML Code -

```html
<div class="row"> <!-- 2 --> 

            <form class="row g-3" action="<?= $data['action'] ?>" method="post"><!-- 3 -->

                <div class="col-sm-12 survey-tabs"> <!-- 4 -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" hidden>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Contact & Site Details</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Questions</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Site Details</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content"><!-- 5 -->
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                            <h1>Contact & Site Details</h1>
                            <div class="row">                   <!-- START TAB ROW 1 -->
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                            <label for="site_name" class="form-label">Site Name*</label>
                                            <input type="text"
                                                class="form-control"
                                                id="site_name"
                                                name="site_name"
                                                value="<?= $data['record']['site_name'] ?? '' ?>"
                                                placeholder="Enter Site Name"
                                                required><br>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                            <label for="poNum" class="form-label">PO Number*</label>
                                            <input type="text"
                                                class="form-control"
                                                id="poNum"
                                                name="poNum"
                                                value="<?= $data['record']['poNum'] ?? '' ?>"
                                                placeholder="Enter PO Num (Given in Email)"
                                                required>
                                </div>

                            <div class="tab-control">
                                <a class="next-button" role="button"><button class="btn btn-primary">Next</button></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->


                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                            <h1>Questions</h1>
                            <div class="row"><!-- START TAB ROW 2 -->
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <h6 for="current_machine">1. What is your Current Machine?</h6>
                                        <input type="text"
                                               class="form-control"
                                               id="current_machine"
                                               name="current_machine"
                                               value="<?= $data['record']['current_machine'] ?? '' ?>"
                                               placeholder="Leave blank if none"><br>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <h6 for="ordered_machine">2. What Machine did you Order?*</h6>
                                        <input type="text"
                                               class="form-control"
                                               id="ordered_machine"
                                               name="ordered_machine"
                                               value="<?= $data['record']['ordered_machine'] ?? '' ?>"
                                               placeholder="Machine(s) Ordered"
                                               required> <br>
                                </div>

                            </div> <!-- END TAB ROW 2 -->

                            <div class="tab-control">
                                <a class="previous-button" role="button"><i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-3x fa-fw"></i></a>
                                <a class="next-button" role="button"><button class="btn btn-primary">Next</button></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->


                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                            <h1>Site Details</h1>
                            <div class="row"><!-- START TAB ROW 3 -->
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <h6 for="q7">9. What floor is the Machine(s) going to be located on?</h6>
                                        <input type="text"
                                            class="form-control"
                                            id="q7"
                                            name="q7"
                                            value="<?= $data['record']['q7'] ?? '' ?>"
                                            placeholder="Please enter what floor your machine will be located on"> <br><br>
                                </div>

                            </div> <!-- END TAB ROW 3 -->

                            <div class="tab-control">
                                <a class="previous-button" role="button"><i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-3x fa-fw"></i></a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3"><?= $data['button'] ?></button>
                            </div>

                        </div>




                    </div><!-- 5 -->

                </div><!-- 4 -->

            </form><!-- 3 -->

        </div> <!-- 2 -->

    </div><!-- 1 -->
```

Comment: The simplest thing is to probably not use a `<button>` tag so that form validation doesn't kick in, at least if I'm understanding things correctly. You could also disable the fields on the hidden screens, which should probably work, too.

Comment: i will replace the button with an A tag. And how do you mean by disabling the fields. Disable the ones that aren't open? Wouldnt that not save the inputted data? I am unsure honestly...

Comment: @ChrisHaas I replaced the buttons with an a tag as before, and it didnt do that weird glitch. But the form does not submit...

Comment: You aren't saving the data when someone clicks "Next", are you? I'm not seeing that in your sample. You could wrap each "screen" in a fieldset and disable "future" screens. If you allow someone to click next/previous on a whim without complete each screen first, that's when things get more complicated.

Comment: I meant how when you switch tabs you can see the data that was previously entered. I thought if you disabled them then you wouldnt be able to.

Comment: You are in the middle of a bunch of features that are competing, and one or more of these are going to have to give. If you want native HTML field validation (which I'd recommend), you'll have to find a way to instruct the browser to only look at certain fields. You can do this by disabling them, but then as you noted the submit breaks. You could break the screens into multiple forms, but you can only submit one. I don't have a perfect recommendation for you, unfortunately. For me, I think I would use multiple forms and throw AJAX at this, but that introduces more complexity, obviously.

Comment: Yeah I don't think I would have time for that. I only have a short period left for this project. I may just have to use the one form that shows everything. The only downfall this is quite long.